# Какая польза от DTO?

Tags: entity, dto

Может кто-нибудь объяснить на пальцах зачем нужен DTO? Я прошерстил гугл, но так и не нашел простого ответа с понятным примером? Я понимаю, что можно обойтись без этого паттерна, а обойтись лишь @Entity, но можно пример, который раскрывал бы достоинства этого паттерна?

Answer (score 2):

`DTO` объекты используются для сериализации данных и передачей их между системами, и соответственно для десериализации обратно в объект, то есть являются объектами передачи данных. `DTO` объекты не содержат поведения и не содержат методов бизнес логики.

Answer (score 1):

Для отсечения лишних данных, полученных например из БД. На фронт чаще всего весь такой объект отправлять незачем, да и безопасности это может угрожать если злые люди узнают о внутреннем устройстве бэкенда. Поэтому все служебные поля нужно отсекать